# MySQL query to update players weekly ranking positions with large dataset

Tags: mysql, sql, ranking

I'm trying to update weekly ranking scores for players, but any query I have tried just runs to timeout. There are around 100k rows in the table. My table *players_weekly_rankings* looks like this:

```
player_id | ranking_points | yearweek | ranking_pos
22        | 1676           | 2020/01  | 1
12        | 1620           | 2020/01  | 2
45        | 1620           | 2020/01  | 2
53        | 1544           | 2020/01  | 4
25        | 1644           | 2020/02  | 1
21        | 1555           | 2020/02  | 2
etc.
```

So the ranking_pos column is the one being updated.

And the query that never finishes and runs to timeout:

```
update players_weekly_ranking
set ranking_pos = (
    select count(distinct ranking_points) + 1
    from (SELECT ranking_points, yearweek FROM players_weekly_ranking) w2
    where w2.yearweek = players_weekly_ranking.yearweek and w2.ranking_points > players_weekly_ranking.ranking_points
)
```

And the EXPLAIN as requested below (this test tebale has only 2000 records, but actual table near 100k)
[image]

With upto couple of thousand rows, it finishes in two minutes, but anything above that, timeout is reached.

Is there more optimized way to do this, so the query wouldn't run to timeout? Thanks!

Comment: Please share more details, like the `EXPLAIN` output for the given query

Comment: I updated the query result into the table structure above.

Comment: The innermost subquery is redundant. It doesn't need to be a subquery

Comment: Ok, but how would it look like without a subquery?

Comment: Please add the result of `EXPLAIN` to your question by editing it

Comment: Have you added an index on yearweek field?

Comment: Yes, it had index, but very good point!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this should do the trick in a single pass (no subqueries)

```
SET @rank = 0;

UPDATE players_weekly_ranking
SET ranking_pos = (@rank := @rank+1)
WHERE yearweek = '2020/01'
ORDER BY ranking_points DESC;
```

It defines a variable `@rank` starting at 0, then iterates over all rows for a specific `yearweek`, by descending `ranking_points` and assigns their `ranking_pos`. `(@rank := @rank+1)` is there to increment the variable at each row.

**Edit:** I'm assuming you only need to update the ranking for a specific week, since scores in the past should not change

**Edit2:** Here is a version that takes into account equal points and can update several yearweeks:

```
SET @rank = 0; -- rank of the previous row
SET @yearweek = ''; -- yearweek of the previous row
SET @last_score = 0; -- score of the previous row
SET @nb_same_score = 0; -- number of rows "in a row" with same score

UPDATE players_weekly_ranking
SET ranking_pos = IF(
        @yearweek != (@yearweek := yearweek), 
        IF( -- if it's a new yearweek
            (@last_score := ranking_points) AND (@nb_same_score:=1),
            (@rank := 1), -- first row always gets ranking_pos = 1
            0
        ), 
        IF( -- if same yearweek
            @last_score = (@last_score := ranking_points) AND (@nb_same_score := @nb_same_score + 1),
            @rank, -- if same score as last row => set same ranking_pos
            @rank := @rank + @nb_same_score + (@nb_same_score := 1) -1
        )
    )
ORDER BY yearweek, ranking_points DESC;
```

Iterating over each rows, ordered by yearweek and points, this does the following:

- if its a new week, the rank for the first row (highest score) is always 1. (`@yearweek` takes the value of the new week, `@last_score` & `@nb_same_score` are reset)
- if it's the same week as last row, `@last_score` is compared with the row's score (and updated). If they are equal, `@nb_same_score` is incremented

  - If equal, the row gets the same rank as the previous one
  - otherwise it gets + `@nb_same_score` to its rank. (`(@nb_same_score := 1) -1` is just there to reset the `@nb_same_score` variable to 1)

Comment: Actually I need to update rankings to the part for at least one year, so I think this one wouldn't work. And I think this doesn't take into consideration the equal rankings with players with same score.

Comment: You are correct, it's not taking into account same scores :< I'll update it in a bit!

Comment: @user3112031 I added a new version under **edit2**. It should work for several yearweek, and handles players with same score

Comment: Excellent! Your last query works like a charm and finishes in just a few seconds. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

1. Replace sub-query with JOIN
2. In the JOIN'ed table calculate the rank using window-function RANK(). It will do exactly what you need.

RANK() is available only in MySQL 8+ https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_rank

If you have MySQL 5.* look for workarounds without RANK() function: [Rank function in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3333665/rank-function-in-mysql)

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have MySQL 8 available at my hosting provider :(

Comment: That's really sad because MySQL 8 has been released few years ago. But you have an option to mimic RANK() function using variables.